# Cannot convert Task object to Task SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I am creating a simple class but I am getting `Cannot convert Task object to Task SqlDataReader`. Here is my code,

```
public static class SqlHelper
{
    enum ExecutionType
    {
        NonQuery,
        Reader,
        Scaler

    }
    public static async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(string connectionString, CommandType commandType,
        string commandText,
        params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        return (Task<int>)ExecuteAsync(ExecutionType.NonQuery, connectionString, commandType, commandText, parameters);
    }


    public static async Task<SqlDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(string connectionString, CommandType commandType,
        string commandText, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        return (Task<SqlDataReader>)ExecuteAsync(ExecutionType.Reader, connectionString, commandType, commandText, parameters);
    }

    public static async Task<object> ExecuteScalarAsync(string connectionString, CommandType commandType, string commandText,
        params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        return ExecuteAsync(ExecutionType.Scaler, connectionString, commandType, commandText, parameters);
    }


    private static async Task<object> ExecuteAsync(ExecutionType executionType, string connectionString, CommandType commandType, string commandText,
        params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection) { CommandType = commandType })
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                if (executionType == ExecutionType.Reader)
                {
                    return await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                }
                if (executionType == ExecutionType.NonQuery)
                {
                    return await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
                return await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Any suggestion to fix this issue will be appreciated?

Comment: No such error message exists. Please post the exact compiler error/exception and say where it happened and what you did to resolve it. Post less code.

Comment: Note also that `ExecuteScalarAsync` does not need to be `async` here: it is simply returning the original `Task<object>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cast a `Task<object>` to a `Task<Foo>`. What you want instead is:

```
return (Foo) await (expression);
```

i.e.

```
public static async Task<SqlDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(
    string connectionString, CommandType commandType,
    string commandText, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    return (SqlDataReader) await ExecuteAsync(ExecutionType.Reader,
        connectionString, commandType, commandText, parameters);
}
```

(and likewise for the `int` version)

Note: you might also want to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all of your `await` expressions. For example:

```
public static async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(string connectionString,
    CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    return (int) await ExecuteAsync(ExecutionType.NonQuery, connectionString,
        commandType, commandText, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It will return immediately to the caller?

Comment: @user960567 that depends on a *lot* of things; but in the *typical* case, it will return an incomplete task to the caller once it has been processed by ADO.NET - exactly the same as when using ADO.NET directly.

Comment: Thanks. As a side note, This is a replacement of microsoft SqlHelper that my application uses(only added the required methods). Is you see any issue in the code?

Comment: @user960567 well, it isn't how I would *personally* implement it; you can avoid a layer of wrapping/unwrapping if you have dedicated methods that return the right thing rather than always returning `Task<object>`; and as I already mentioned: add `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. Personally, I find it very peculiar to *pass in* `SqlParameter` instances - it removes all useful and meaningful abstraction; but, I understand that is what `SqlHelper` does, so that may not be an option to change. Other observations: this doesn't allow for re-using a connection, or for raw ADO.NET transactions.

Comment: I always appreciate your help.

Comment: Isn't connection reused by the connection pool?

Comment: @user960567 that doesn't help you do things where you want to use a single connection repeatedly - for example, anything involving an ADO.NET transaction, or anything involving a connection-level temporary table (`#foo` etc), or connection-level `SET` options, or impersonation, or... (etc)